# QueryOver - I thought ID's were free?

Tags: nhibernate, subquery, queryover

It took me a while, but I figured out how to get what I want - mostly.
My code:

```
        var sq = QueryOver.Of<VehicleGroup>(() => vehicleGroup)
                    .JoinQueryOver<Manager>(vg => vg.Managers)
                        .Where(man => man.Id == managerId)
                    .JoinQueryOver<TruckPCBase>(() => vehicleGroup.Vehicles)
                        .Where(v => v.Id == item.VehicleId)
                    .Select(vg => vg.Id)
                    ;

        var vp = Session.QueryOver<Summary>(() => item)
            .WithSubquery.WhereExists(sq)
            .Take(10)
            .List();
```

This returns exactly what I want.

HOWEVER, I had to map an additional field to make it work.

The Summary object has a VehicleBase component.  What I wanted to do was:

```
        var sq = QueryOver.Of<VehicleGroup>(() => vehicleGroup)
                    .JoinQueryOver<Manager>(vg => vg.Managers)
                        .Where(man => man.Id == managerId)
                    .JoinQueryOver<TruckPCBase>(() => vehicleGroup.Vehicles)
                        .Where(v => v.Id == item.VehicleBase.Id)
                    .Select(vg => vg.Id)
                    ;

        var vp = Session.QueryOver<Summary>(() => item)
            .WithSubquery.WhereExists(sq)
            .Take(10)
            .List();
```

This gives the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at lambda_method(ExecutionScope )
```

Ok, so I added an additional fetch:

```
        var sq = QueryOver.Of<VehicleGroup>(() => vehicleGroup)
                    .JoinQueryOver<Manager>(vg => vg.Managers)
                        .Where(man => man.Id == managerId)
                    .JoinQueryOver<TruckPCBase>(() => vehicleGroup.Vehicles)
                        .Where(v => v.Id == item.VehicleBase.Id)
                    .Select(vg => vg.Id)
                    ;

        var vp = Session.QueryOver<Summary>(() => item)
            .Fetch(sum => sum.VehicleBase).Eager
            .WithSubquery.WhereExists(sq)
            .Take(10)
            .List();
```

No dice.  I don't want to add a new property to my Summary class (VehicleId) - I want to access it through Summary.VehicleBase.Id

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fully understand what you are trying to do however the issue appears to be :

you are getting this exception because  for this line

```
.Where(v => v.Id == item.VehicleBase.Id)
```

`item` is null.
The linq expression evaluator for nhibernate will try to eagerly evaluate everything that doesn't include the lambda parameter. For this case:

`v.Id  =>` will be evaluated later and turned to HQL
`item.VehicleBase.Id =>` no dependency to `v` so evaluator will evaluate it eagerly which will throw an NRE.

Comment: So, how do I set up the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work!!!

```
var sq = QueryOver.Of<VehicleGroup>()
    .Inner.JoinAlias(vg => vg.Managers, () => manager)
    .Where(() => manager.Id == managerId)
    .JoinQueryOver(x => x.Vehicles, () => vehicle)
    .Select(x => vehicle.Id)
    ;


var vp = Session.QueryOver<Summary>()
    .Fetch(vpr => vpr.VehicleBase).Eager
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.VehicleBase.Id).In(sq)
    .Take(10)
    .List()
    ;
```

This generates the following SQL

```
SELECT
    TOP (@p0) this_.summaryID as summaryID42_1_,
    ... close to 200 columns cut ...
FROM
    dbo.Summary this_ 
left outer join
    dbo.Vehicle vehiclebas2_ 
        on this_.VehicleID = vehiclepcbas2_.VehicleID 
WHERE
    this_.vehicleID in (
        SELECT
            vehicle2_.vehicleID as y0_ 
        FROM
            dbo.Groups this_0_ 
        inner join
            dbo.Manager_Rel managers4_ 
                on this_0_.groupId=managers4_.groupId 
        inner join
            dbo.Managers manager1_ 
                on managers4_.managerId=manager1_.ManagerId 
        inner join
            dbo.Object_Rel vehicles6_ 
                on this_0_.groupId=vehicles6_.groupId 
        inner join
            dbo.Vehicle vehicle2_ 
                on vehicles6_.ID=vehicle2_.VehicleID 
        WHERE
            this_0_.type=1 
            AND manager1_.ManagerId = @p1
    );
@p0 = 10 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p1 = 34 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

Exactly (I think) what I wanted.